# Line is not Wrapping in Terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, terminal

I am using Ubuntu G-NOME 16.04. Line wrapping not functioning properly in my terminal. It starts rewrite at the beginning of the same line.
eg.
If I try to type follwining command
**user@MY-PC: ~$/home/user/abc/def/configuration/config.file**

It will go something like:
**config.file ~$/home/user/abc/def/configuration/**

instead of:
**user@MY-PC: ~$/home/user/abc/def/configuration/

config.file**

my PS1 variable in .bashrc is
**PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\e[0;34m\u\e[0;35m@\e[0;92m\h:\e[0;96m\w\e[0;31m\$\e[0m'**

Please someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape sequences that don't advance the cursor (e.g. `\e[0;34m` to change color) need to be enclosed between `\[` and `\]` in PS1.

This is described in the "PROMPTING" section of bash's manual page.

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Comment: Care to share the PS1 you tried?

Comment: PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[0;34m\]\u\e\[[0;35m\]@\[\e[0;92m\]\h:\[\e[0;96m\]\w\[\e[0;31m\]\$\[\e[0m\]'

Comment: I said `\[` and `\]`, not `[` and `]`. Also, `\e[[0;35m]` misplaces the opening tag. Do it carefully and precisely and it'll work. (Btw this question has probably a dozen duplicates here on stackoverflow. I'm outta here, can't help you any further in this easy step.)